# Assigning Records VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl, record, xilinx, intel-fpga

Good time to everyone.

Resently I try to improve code in new project and found some interesting decoder.
It has 2 processes: in first all data formed and in second all bus triggered in out registers by control signal. But some wires need to be reset in some period of time (in second process).

So I deside to write this code for correct resettind some signals ([cm_regA/cm_regB] are records with different types of data):

```
----------------------------------------
LOAD_DATA_PROCESS: process(clk_i)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    if (reset_reg) then
      cm_regB.reg_1 <= '0';
      cm_regB.reg_2 <= '0';
      cm_regB.reg_3 <= '0';
      cm_regB.reg_4 <= '0';
    else
      if (load_reg) then
        cm_regB <= cm_regA;
      else null;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
----------------------------------------
```

But this construction Synthesized with lot of multiplexers betwen reg_5...reg_10, so next code give me good synthesized construction and great speed:

```
----------------------------------------
LOAD_DATA_PROCESS: process(clk_i)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    if (reset_reg) then
      cm_regB.reg_1 <= '0';
      cm_regB.reg_2 <= '0';
      cm_regB.reg_3 <= '0';
      cm_regB.reg_4 <= '0';
    else
      if (load_reg) then
        cm_regB.reg_1 <= cm_regA.reg_1;
        cm_regB.reg_2 <= cm_regA.reg_2;
        cm_regB.reg_3 <= cm_regA.reg_3;
        cm_regB.reg_4 <= cm_regA.reg_4;
      else null;
      end if;
    end if;

    if (load_reg) then
      cm_regB.reg_5  <= cm_regA.reg_5;
      cm_regB.reg_6  <= cm_regA.reg_6;
      cm_regB.reg_7  <= cm_regA.reg_7;
      cm_regB.reg_8  <= cm_regA.reg_8;
      cm_regB.reg_9  <= cm_regA.reg_9;
      cm_regB.reg_10  <= cm_regA.reg_10;
    else null;
    end if;

  end if;
end process;
----------------------------------------
```

So the questions next:

1. How make this construction more compact (like first example)?
2. Or how to make any changes in buses [cm_regA/cm_regB] visible for second example (in case changing first process and forgot add this changes to LOAD_DATA_PROCESS)?

P.S. Type of cm_regA and cm_regB are declarated in package. Here it is:

```
----------------------------------------
type cm_t is record
    reg_1   : STD_LOGIC;
    reg_2   : STD_LOGIC;
    reg_3   : STD_LOGIC;   
    reg_4   : STD_LOGIC;
    reg_5   : STD_LOGIC;
    reg_6   : BOOLEAN;
    reg_7   : STD_LOGIC;
    reg_8   : STD_LOGIC;
    reg_9   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(CONST_1-1 downto 0);
    reg_10  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(CONST_2-1 downto 0);
end record cm_t;
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
The problem is partially caused because most synthesizer's support for VHDL `record` types is not great. You should use an array instead. And you should separate the registers with reset from the registers without reset. It is very hard for the synthesis software to determine the overall type of `cm_regB`, because it is not one type. You will instead infer latches.

Comment: ... and drop the `else null;` because that makes no sense.

Comment: A minimal, complete and verifiable example would demonstrate a specific problem that can be addressed. Are elements reg_1 through reg_10 all of the same scalar type? If so cm_regA and cm_regB can be array types. Also if cm_regA and cm_regB are of the same record type and there are only 10 elements (reg_1 through reg_10) `cm_regB <= cm_regA;` If you need to access fields and cm_regA and cm_regB are of the same record type your record elements can be array types. Show the record type and cm_regA and cm_regB declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your first code, you are indeed adding a dependency to `reset` for `reg_5` to `reg_10`. This is because of the if-else statement. This is the effective code you write for these registers.

```
if not(reset_reg) and load_reg then
    cm_regB.reg_5 <= cm_regA.reg_5;
    [...]
    cm_regB.reg_10 <= cm_regA.reg_10;
end if;
```

So, you should separate the reset block from the other assignment. You can achieve that by using the fact that for signals *only the last assignment* in a process will be applied the next delta cycle. So something like this:

```
LOAD_DATA_PROCESS: process(clk_i)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_i) then
        if load_reg then
            cm_regB <= cm_regA;
        end if;
        if reset_reg then
            cm_regB.reg_1 <= '0';
            cm_regB.reg_2 <= '0';
            cm_regB.reg_3 <= '0';
            cm_regB.reg_4 <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's really help! Is this works for all types set/reset and synchronous/asynchronous signals?

Comment: @NikolayJoshKonovalenko uhm, your question seem rather broad. So I don't know if it will work in the other cases your are thinking of.